# Setting View height programmatically Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I defined a custom view with a public method:

```
public void setHeight(int height) {
    //this.getLayoutParams().height = height; --- NOT WORKING
    this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height)); // --- WORKING
```

When I use the comment out code it doesn't work (meaning that the view height is not changing when calling this method), but when I use the second phrase it's working as expected.

What can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy - just look at the code of `setLayoutParams()`:

```
 public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
     if (params == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException("Layout parameters cannot be null");
     }
     mLayoutParams = params;
     if (mParent instanceof ViewGroup) {
         ((ViewGroup) mParent).onSetLayoutParams(this, params);
     }
     requestLayout();
 }
```

See? It's calling `requestLayout()` after setting the layout params.

Btw.: The Android source code can be found at [www.grepcode.com](http://www.grepcode.com) and is often quite helpful.